# Working with weather API and code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT' appears

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, openweathermap

So, I'm working with a weather API to get the latitude and the weather of different places.

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const https = require("https");
const {
  restart
} = require('nodemon');

const app = express();

app.get('/demo', async(req, res) => {
  const units = "metric"
  const city = "Santiago"

  const urlLatitude = "https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?appid=" + apiKey + "&limit=5&q=" + city

  const lat1 = getLatitude.data[0].lat
  const lon1 = getLatitude.data[0].lon

  const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat1 + "&lon=" + lon1 + "&appid=" + apiKey + "&units=" + units

  const getWeather = await axios.get(url)

  const temp = getWeather.data.main.temp
  const description = getWeather.data.weather[0].description
  const icon = getWeather.data.weather[0].icon
  const imageURL = ("http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png")

  console.log(temp)
  console.log(description)
  res.json({ message: getWeather.data })

})


app.listen(3001, function() {
  console.log("http://localhost:3001/demo")
})
```

Then when I go to the localhost:3001/demo I can see all the data I ask but in my console, this message appears. Every time a make the call works fine but in the console, this error shows up.

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
http://localhost:3001/demo
Server is running on port 3001
23.88
overcast clouds
node:internal/errors:484
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:607:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\ValentinaT\Documents\WebDevelopment\WeatherProyect\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\ValentinaT\Documents\WebDevelopment\WeatherProyect\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:275:10)
    at C:\Users\ValentinaT\Documents\WebDevelopment\WeatherProyect\app.js:50:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

Node.js v18.9.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Can anyone explain why that is happening?

Comment: Where do you send the data to the client? I don't see `res.send` or `res.json` anywhere

Comment: You're executing setHeader multiple times for a same request, not sure why, maybe you've got more code to share for us to be able and assist.

Comment: The code you have given is not part of the error `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` which occurs when response have already been sent, but your function continues executing (like in my personal mistakes of forgotten `return` statement) and further down the line another response method is triggered.

Comment: I forgot to add a line in the code, sorry!     res.json({ message: getWeather.data })
is alredy added